# Google Pie Chart is not displaying at all in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, pie-chart

I have a simple Pie Chart that displays fine in FireFox or Chrome but doesn't display in IE9. I just get a white screen, nothing else in IE9. Can someone help me figure out what is wrong and help me fix this? Thanks a lot.

```
<html>  
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Timeline', 'Likage'],
          ['Badeurlaub', #c_0001#],
          ['Aktiv-/Sport-Urlaub', #c_0002#],
          ['Kultur-/Bildungsreise', #c_0003#],
          ['Kreuzfahrt/Rundreise', #c_0004#],
          ['Sonstiges', #c_0005#],
        ]);

       var options = {
          title: ' ',
          colors: ['#686800', '#8E8E40', '#a6a6a6', '#40B3D9', '#0099cc']
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
      }    
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the hashtags in your array be quoted, or perhaps they are unreplaced placeholders in your back-end script. Very likely IE breaks on this.